# Load a Perl Hash into Java

Tags: java, xml, perl, data-structures, hash

I have a big `.pm` File, which only consist of a very big Perl hash with lots of subhashes. I have to load this hash into a Java program, do some work and changes on the data lying below and save it back into a `.pm` File, which should look similar to the one i started with.

By now, i tried to convert it linewise by regex and string matching, converting it into a XML Document and later Elementwise parse it back into a perl hash.

This somehow works, but seems quite dodgy. Is there any more reliable way to parse the perl hash without having a perl runtime installed?

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right, it's utterly filthy. Regex and string for XML in the first place is a horrible idea, and honestly XML is probably not a good fit  for this anyway.

I would suggest that you consider `JSON`. I would be stunned to find `java` can't handle `JSON` and it's inherently a hash-and-array oriented data structure.

So you can quite literally:

```
use JSON;
print to_json ( $data_structure, { pretty => 1 } );
```

Note - it won't work for serialising objects, but for perl hash/array/scalar type structures it'll work just fine.

You can then import it back into perl using:

```
my $new_data = from_json $string;
print Dumper $new_data;
```

Either `Dumper` it to a file, but given you requirement is multi-language going forward, just using native JSON as your 'at rest' data is probably a more sensible choice.

But if you're looking at parsing *perl code* within java, without a perl interpreter? No, that's just insanity.

Comment: I was hoping maybe there is a perl Interpreter library for Java, as i have found None. But your answer makes me more doubting, that there is any

Comment: I think it phenomenally unlikely, because `perl` is the "perl interpreter" that you're looking for. I can't imagine anyone rewriting perl as a java library just because they don't want to install `perl` _and_ `java`.

Comment: Yeah, if it wouldn't had to be Plattform Independent, i would include a local perl Parser, as reading a hash does not need many packages. Well at least the hash has a consisten structure, so parsing it and reading key & value from it is somehow possible, but i am afraid of users entering bad written hashes

Comment: How are the hashes 'written'? An export-via-JSON really shouldn't be hard. Or for the really filthy option - POST it via a CGI webserver, to jsonify the hash code :)

Comment: Those hashes are written on a different machine and contain configuration Settings, so they might also be manipulated by users manually. Exporting them to JSON while creation is impossible like this as i can not integrate into this flow